# How can I make an input text inside an popover autocomplete

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-autocomplete, textinput, popover

I have an popover which has one button and one input text. This popover opens whenever I click on an specific image. I'd like to make the input text inside the popover become autocompleted.

Here's what I've got now: http://jsfiddle.net/HhpnN/

I think my jQuery function is not recognizing my .textData class because I created this input text in an img attribute (data-content). Here's the input text creation:

```
data-content="<input type='text' class='textData' /> <input type='button' class='btn' value='Save' />"
```

Answer (score 3):

When you say "autocomplete", do you mean you would like the results to begin filling as you type?  This would be what is called Typeahead.  You will need to update your input tag with the appropriate data elements:

```
<input type='text' data-provide='typeahead' data-items='4' data-source='[&quot;thisquot;,&quot;is&quot;,&quot;an&quot;,&quot;array&quot;,&quot;or&quot;,&quot;data&quot;]'>
```

You will also need to provide the data set for it search against.  You can do this inline, as I have in the example below, or by defining a source.

Here is an update of your example, typeahead for names of US States:

http://jsfiddle.net/dusthaines/HhpnN/3/

More details on their site at: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

Comment: It works perfectly in jsfiddle, that's what I want to do! but when I copy exactly the same code to my webpage, it doesn't work.. I have downloaded the bootstrap-typeahead.js (and added the line: <script src="js/bootstrap-typeahead.js" type="text/javascript"></script> ) as well, but nothing done. When I create an input text outside of the popover, it works normally. The problem is when I put it inside an popover. What can I be missing here?

Comment: hi felipe, not sure what the problem could be. perhaps your issue is now CSS related? i know in some of the older versions there were issues with z-index preventing content from displaying properly.